# Windows Subsystems for Linux export with `wsl.exe --export <distro> <archive>` fails

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, export

I am trying to export a `WSL`distribution with:

```
wsl.exe --export Debian C:\Users\lalebarde\Documents\wsl_debian.tar
```

But it returns silently after one minute. No file is created, no error message. The distribution is correctly listed and is working. Of course, I have tried when it is not running.

How could I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you add the output of `wsl -l -v`?

Comment: First, nothing, then I have rebooted, and it works again, `wsl -l -v` returns `NAME STATE VERSION`, `*Debian STOPPED 1`, `Ubuntu 16.04 STOPPED 1`. Export works also as expected, I can see the archive file growing. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Oh no, it's fine :-) .... WSL still being buggy, caused me trouble too when I exported for the first time.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was resolved with a reboot of the system and can no longer be reproduced

Comment: Sure, thank you. Alternatively, I can delete it if it is better?